# Merge two text files line by line in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file, text, merge

I'm trying to figure out how to merge two text files line by line. The letters file contains letters in a column A to I. Numbers contains numbers in a column from 1 to 9. This is what I have so far:

```
file='C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Desktop\\numbers.txt'
f = File.open(file, "r")
f.each_line { |line|
  dile='C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Desktop\\letters.txt'
  d = File.open(dile, "r")
  d.each_line { |dine| 
    this = line + dine 
    print this
  }
}
```

But my results are like this:

```
1
A
1
B
1
C
1
D
1
E
1
F
1
G
1
H
1
I
1
J2
A
2
B
2
C
2
D
2
E
2
F
2
G
2
H
2
I
2
J3
A
3
B
3
C
3
D
3
E
3
F
3
G
3
H
3
I
3
J4
A
4
B
4
C
4
D
4
E
4
F
4
G
4
H
4
I
4
J5
A
5
B
5
C
5
D
5
E
5
F
5
G
5
H
5
I
5
J6
A
6
B
6
C
6
D
6
E
6
F
6
G
6
H
6
I
6
J7
A
7
B
7
C
7
D
7
E
7
F
7
G
7
H
7
I
7
J8
A
8
B
8
C
8
D
8
E
8
F
8
G
8
H
8
I
8
J9
A
9
B
9
C
9
D
9
E
9
F
9
G
9
H
9
I
9
J10A
10B
10C
10D
10E
10F
10G
10H
10I
10J
```

When what I really want is something like this:

```
1A
2B
3C
4D
5E
6F
7G
8H
9I
```

Anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Could you please give the input of your two files `numbers.txt` and `letters.txt` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f1, f2 = [
  'C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Desktop\\numbers.txt',
  'C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Desktop\\letters.txt'
]


File.readlines(f1).map(&:chomp)
                  .zip(File.readlines(f2).map(&:chomp))
                  .map(&:join)
```

or, without double chomping:

```
File.readlines(f1).zip(File.readlines(f2))
                  .map(&:join)
                  .map { |s| s.gsub /#$//, '' }
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 1):

Its because each line already carries line feed `\n`. Try using [`chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp):

```
this = line.chomp + dine.chomp
```

Comment: Ahh I've added it to the original question: The letters file contains letters in a column A to I. Numbers contains numbers in a column from 1 to 9

Answer (score 1):

Like a [@mudasobwa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33152755/2057388) answer

```
=> File.readlines('num').zip(File.readlines('let')).flat_map { |x| x.map(&:chomp!).join }
=> [
  [0] "1A",
  [1] "2B",
  [2] "3C",
  [3] "4D",
  [4] "5E"
]
```

<sub>just without double `chomp`</sub>